# ng-pattern not working when limiting to 24 characters with regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, forms, input

We have the following input field and we want the error message to show when the user has inputted 25 characters. However, it is only showing when the user has put in 26 characters.

Here is the input field.

[image: Input Field with 26 charcters]

Here is the RegEx: `/^.{0,24}$/` 
I have also tried: `^.{0,24}$`

Why is this not working when the user hits 25 characters?
Also, we are using angular `1.3.10` if this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be working, like it is highlighting input fields when it is not satisfying provided pattern in `ng-pattern`. Also it gives error after `25` because it starts with `0` to `24` since it makes an field invalid when its you are entering `26`

[**Plunkr Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mj4UDMXo1K8ktD9sbq1S?p=preview)

---

As you are just worried about to enter character till 25 length, I'd say Despite of `ng-pattern` use `ng-maxlength` attribute by specifying length in it.

```
<input ng-model="myModel" ng-maxlength="25"/>
```

Comment: Yes - we understand this is a possibility. However, this is a large code base and would like to stay with the regular pattern.

Comment: But we do believe this is the best way to go in the future.

Comment: @ChrisBolton I read your question again & it seems working correctly..please look at my updated answer